# Problem install latest Firefox on Debian stable

Tags: debian, apt

I'm using Debian stable and I want to install the latest Firefox.

So I put the unstable source in my sources.list.
I run this command `sudo apt install unstable -t firefox`  and I got this:

```
gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.30.2-9~deb10u1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: by not doing what you are doing: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian

Comment: I will read the page to get more info

Comment: According to http://mozilla.debian.net/, Firefox release Debian package is unfortunately not supported on Debian stable but only on Debian testing (with `apt-get install -t unstable firefox`) and unstable. So it looks like on Debian stable, you either have to install the Firefox ESR Debian package or the official release binary from Mozilla. This is not very convenient and a reason why I use Ubuntu on desktop and Debian on servers only.

Answer (score 4):

It’s rarely a good idea to mix and match Debian releases (see [the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) for details). In many cases, you can’t install packages from unstable in a Debian 10 system without upgrading much if not most of the system to unstable.

If you want Firefox 83, I suspect the only straightforward option is to download it from Mozilla and install it manually.